# How to bind a popup and image together in javaquery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, popupwindow

I have downloaded a javascript datetime picker from the following source

http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/download/sample.zip

I dragged this file in my asp.net form .
now on clicking on the calender image ,calender popup at the position

```
position: absolute; 
left: -1px; 
top: 0px; 
width: 208px; 
border: 1pt solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
padding: 0px; 
cursor: move; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
z-index: 100;
```

means at the start of the page.
How can i set its position bounded to the calender image i.e wherever this image is placed popup occurs only at this image

Answer (score 0):

If you use position absolute together with top and left the position is absolute on the page.
BUT
if you use position absolute within an element with position:relative the position is absolute to this element

Dont use top and left or try:

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1')" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend using position fixed rather than absolute, since that will bind the popup to the window, and not the parent element.
when showing the popup you set the top and left properties to be the offset off the image plus what ever offset you want for the popup.

simple jquery:

```
popup.offset(image.offset());
```

I run this function (requires jquery). it set the position to be that of the anchor element, and adjust the popup if the element is too close to the bottom of the window:

```
function showPopup() {
    var offset, difference;
    offset = image.offset();
    popheight = popup.height();
    difference = Math.min(0, $(window).height() - (popup.height() + offset.top + 15))
            // the diffrence betwenn the bottom edge of the popup, and the windows lower edge (+15 to add a bit of space)
    if (difference < 0) {
        offset.top += difference;
    }
    popup.offset(offset);
    screenCover.show().click(hidePopup);
}
```

The screenCover in the last line is a fullscreen div I use to catch clicks out side the popup (since my the popup requires user interaction)

the hidePopup function:

```
function hidePopup() {
    popup.hide();
    screenCover.off('click').hide();
}
```

Comment: should i add these function in the javascript file or in the head section of page